# How should one represent repeating date/time?

Tags: database, date, database-design, time

I'm building a backend at the moment which has a number of objects which have associated dates and times, which repeat at a fixed interval, for instance:

**Object 1**: Repeat Weekly on Tuesdays at 17:00 UTC.

**Object 2**: Repeat on the first Wednesday of the month at 12:00 UTC.

**Object 3**: Repeat every other week (fortnightly) on Friday at 13:00 UTC from January 1, 1970.

I'm looking for the best way to represent this interval in a database, short of generating a calendar file with the object's repeating date/time info in it.

Comment: Maybe mention what database you're using since some may have advanced features that will help you here. Otherwise, try something simple like cron's format. It is extremely flexible, representable in small fixed strings of text, and everyone who's worked on Linux understands it already.

Comment: The cron syntax! Of course! I cannot believe I didn't think of that myself. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to be of inspiration :)